# mysql-Improve a join performance

Tags: mysql

I have a table `PCUI_treat(CUI1,CUI2)`, and I want to combine each value from CUI1 with all values from CUI2. So I use the `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
select distinct t1.CUI1, t2.CUI2 
from PCUI_treat t1 
inner join PCUI_treat t2;
```

But when the number of rows in `PCUI_treat` is high, the performance is bad.
The EXPLAIN like this:
[image: EXPLAIN OUTPUT]

Indexes on CUI1 and CUI2 don't help here, right? How can I improve the performance?

Comment: The results will get exponentially bigger as you add more records, so it is bound to get slower quickly.

Comment: This is a cartesian product, so no, indexes won't help.

Comment: Does it help to do the join on a subquery where the duplicates are already taken out ?

Comment: @SteveSmith No improvement possible? Or query in other ways?

Comment: Irritatingly, despite being an abuse of the clause, GROUP BY is faster than DISTINCT.